# I can't receive emails from the Internet

Tags: exchange-2010

Having installed Exchange 2010 Server and configured it to send and receive Emails, I discover that sending mail is "ok". The problem I'm facing, is receiving Internet mails. I believe it is something to do with my "Public IP Address". My Netgear Router has the LAN IP Address and an Internet IP Address.

LAN IP = 192.xxx.xxx.xxx

Internet IP = 84.xxx.xx.xxx

How can I configure my DNS (and possibly my router) to receive mails from the Internet?

Thank you for your response

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have this set up in your home behind a consumer-grade netgear router, would you?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I configure my DNS (and possibly my router) to receive mails
>   from the Internet?

**DNS**

You'll need to setup an MX record for your email domain with the provider of your domain, creating the appropriate A and MX records (as well as possibly SPF records, etc.)

**router**

You'll need to configure your router/firewall to allow port 25 inbound from that external WAN IP to the Exchange server (along with 80/443 if you want remote OWA and Activesync).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to setup MX records for your domain to point to your public IP.

Then you need to setup your Netgear router to forward traffic using TCP port 25 from the public IP to the local IP of your Exchange server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure an MX DNS record for the public IP address of your mail server for each domain that you wish to receive email on.